# How can I create exactly the same thing in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i want to recreate the same box for my users too. How is this named and how can i recreate it in Flutter? I want the same function as in tinder. My user should be able to select at least 3 interests.

[image]

I made a lot of research but can't find any ways to recreate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ChoiceChip` widget with `Wrap`. Play this widget

```dart
class MyThreeOptions extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyThreeOptions({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyThreeOptions> createState() => _MyThreeOptionsState();
}

class _MyThreeOptionsState extends State<MyThreeOptions> {
  List<int> selectedIndex = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
      spacing: 8,
      runSpacing: 8,
      children: List<Widget>.generate(
        33,
        (int index) {
          return DecoratedBox(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: selectedIndex.contains(index)
                    ? Border.all(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        width: 23,
                      )
                    : null,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24)),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
              child: ChoiceChip(
                elevation: 4,
                selectedColor: Colors.white,
                disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                label: Text(
                  'Item $index',
                  style: selectedIndex.contains(index)
                      ? TextStyle(color: Colors.red)
                      : null,
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                selected: selectedIndex.contains(index),
                onSelected: (bool selected) {
                  if (selectedIndex.contains(index))
                    selectedIndex.remove(index);
                  else
                    selectedIndex.add(index);

                  setState(() {});
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: WOW! Thank you sooooo much!!! I'm new to flutter and my sprint ends on friday and I couldn't find any solution for this problem. Thank you!!